# Why React based Wordpress plugin shortcode content is not rendered?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, webpack, wordpress-plugin-creation, pangolin

Why React based Wordpress plugin does not render "content" in the div?

Following the Pangolin tutorial to make plugin: https://github.com/gopangolin/wp-reactivate

I have an admin menu, with the main item and the sub item, in Admin.php I do this modification:

Added these lines in `enqueue_admin_scripts`

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-admin-script-2', plugins_url( 'assets/js/admin2.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array( 'jquery' ), $this->version );

            wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-admin-script-2', 'twppwr_object', array(
                'api_nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
                'api_url'     => rest_url( $this->plugin_slug . '/v1/' ),
                )
            );
```

Created the submenu:

```
/*
        * Add submenus to the Tikex menu.
        */
        add_submenu_page(
            $this->plugin_slug,
            __( 'Időpontok', $this->plugin_slug ),
            __( 'Időpontok', $this->plugin_slug ),
            'manage_options',
            $this->plugin_slug . '-admin2',
            array( $this, 'display_admin2_page' )
        );
```

in `webpack.config.js` I added this line:

```
'js/admin2': path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/admin2.js'),
```

I copied `admin.js` and made a `admin2.js` with this content, :

```
/* global window, document */
if (!window._babelPolyfill) {
    require('@babel/polyfill')
}

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Profile from './containers/Profile.jsx'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Profile wpObject={window.twppwr_object} />,
        document.getElementById('tiket-on-wordpress-admin-2')
    )
})
```

Profile.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Profile from './Tikex/Profile'

export default class Shortcode extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Profile initialView={this.props.wpObject.initial_view} />
    }
}

Shortcode.propTypes = {
    wpObject: PropTypes.object,
}
```

and Profile.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Shortcode({}: {}) {
    return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

I see that the div with id `tiket-on-wordpress-admin-2` is created.

But content is empty. Why content is not render in?